# How to print data of a JSON file in a table in the terminal (Python)?

Tags: python, json, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I have a JSON file with multiple elements of the same 'type'
`[{"age":23, "name":"Robert"}, {"age":29, "name":"Simon"}]`
and I want to output them in a table in the terminal. How can I do that?

Comment: What about [tablib](http://docs.python-tablib.org) or `pandas.DataFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of many examples: https://pyformat.info/

```
for i in dic:
    print("%10s, %d"%(i["name"], i["age"]))
```

Comment: then add a view '|' and '-'. I think with this should be very straightforward